# XSL For-Each Loop Selecting a Value within a Value

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

Hello the code is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
  <header/>
    <data>
      <array length="2">      
        <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
          <var name="XXXXX">
            <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
              <var name="disable"><boolean value="false"/></var>
              <var name="alter"><boolean value="true"/></var>
              <var name="username"><string>username1</string></var>
              etc.
```

The code continues with 1000s of username values. I would like to create a loop that selects each username. so far my code for selecting each username looks like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

       <xsl:template match="/">

         <xsl:for-each select='wddxPacket/data/array/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]
                               /var/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var/@name'>
          <xsl:value-of select="username"/>,

          </xsl:for-each>

         </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like my output to look something like: username1,username2,username3,username4....The issue I am facing is my output is either empty or when I change the code to where the value-of select = "@name" I just get an output of username,username,username...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are looping over the `@name` attributes of all `var` elements. If you only want the "username" ones, change it to this...

```
<xsl:for-each select='wddxPacket/data/array/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]
                                /var/struct[[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]
                                /var[@name="username"]'>
```

Then, to get the user name, you can just do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="string"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and advice! Unfortunately, I've tried exactly what you've advised but it did not work. I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: Frstly, check for typos in either the node names or attribute values (Indeed, I just noticed one! It was referring to `struc` instead of `struct`, so I have corrected this in my answer). Also, does you actual xml have namespaces, as this would affect things too.

Comment: There aren't any namespaces, I've checked for typos. What confuses me is when I write 
<xsl:value-of select='wddxPacket/data/array/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var[@name="username"]/string'/>

That selects the first value for username perfectly but the same concept won't work when implemented in the loop.

Comment: You might need to edit your question to show a slightly larger XML sample. Small samples are usually preferred, but in this case you might need to show more than one "username". Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your time and help your solution worked after I double checked it many times!! Turns out I did have an extra '/' in my code which was throwing it off.